# Role-based authorisation and TLS

Tags: tls, authentication, authorization

I want to implement role based authorisation in my TLS connections. I.e. when my client authenticates with the server I want them to have certain privileges based on their role.

Are there any provisions in the TLS protocol which facilitate this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

TLS only cares about protecting the communication between two parties and has also an optional mechanism for **authenticate** the client (i.e. client certificates). The latter can be used for basing the **authorization** of the authenticated client on. But apart from that TLS itself does not provide anything to help with the authorization itself.

Comment: Thank you Steffen. Can you elaborate a bit more on how client cert can be used for authorisation?

Comment: @user14475135: *"... how client cert can be used for authorisation"* - I did not say that a client certificate can be used for __authorization__. But usually authorization needs authentication first (there is no point in having user based roles if the user is not known) and __authentication__ can be provided with a client certificate.

Answer (score 0):

TLS iteslf can be used as authentication mechanism, but not as authorization. Authorization is done after authentication and your web server and directory server are responsible for authorization.